# Can I display text object like a mesh?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks, text-object

I have a text (that displays ammo), which looks rather sloppy when it [text] is close to the camera. How would I convert this to a mesh that will still function as a text? I know I can convert it with Alt+C, but it stops functioning as a text object. I saw some videos, and it looks like I will have to use the UV editor with each number separate. How can I have a text display as a mesh, but still keep its function as a text object?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14339/599

Comment: Almost have a working prototype ready for an answer-

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the special text property only found in text objects.

[image]

In this case, I am using Always ➨ And ➨ Property

The property actuator copies another property from a different object.
I am using the cube from [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28485/5426) to change the properties so you can see it updating.

I have two text objects, neither one of them have been transformed into a mesh. they both retain there edibility as a text object.

In this example, the text is white. see [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14340/5426) to change the text color.

[image]

Comment: "neither one of them have been transformed into a mesh. they both retain there edibility as a text object." I want them to be objects but retain text functions.

Comment: What kinda of text functions do you want them to have?

Comment: @X-27 so they don't look 8-bit when camera is close to them.